# How to deal with connections and query queues in node.js node-mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

It is unclear to me how to work that connection and query the collection.
Because sometimes the connection is already there and there is no problem. But when the connection needs to be established, collection queries aren't queued.
You cannot make a new connection all the time either, because you can (and should) make only one.
Seems like you need the collection query in a connection callback, but also stand-alone when the connection is already there.

Ofcourse, this isn't undoable, but with all the blah and yaddah overhead, I imagine I am not doing it right.
After all, this seems kinda *syntactic saccharin* to me.
**Where is the [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)?**

Here's a rudimentary example. Imagine a bunch of requests in the same second:

```
var util        = require('util'),
    mongo       = require('mongodb'),
    Server      = mongo.Server,
    Db          = mongo.Db,
    mServer     = new Server('localhost', 27017),
    mDb         = new Db('SomeDatabase', mServer),
    db;

if (mDb._state == 'disconnected') {
    util.debug('MONGODB: connecting...');
    mDb.open(function(err, newDb) {
        if (!err) {
            db = newDb;
            // I cannot immediately work on a collection here, 
            // because it takes a moment for the db to connect.
        }
    });
}
else if (mDb._state == 'connecting') {
    // I need to catch this state because I cannot work on collections yet, 
    // but I cannot connect either because it's already connecting.
}
// else if (mDb._state == 'connected') {

// Queries need to be performed after connection is established 
// or when connection was already established by a previous request.
db.createCollection(collection, function(err, collection) {
    if (!err) {
        collection.insert(record, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            util.debug('MONGODB: Inserted.');
        });
    }
});

// }
```

Now, the beginner guides I found are all about the callback on `mDb.open`, but this gives problems on successive requests when the node is already running. It refuses to open another connection. **So, what is actually the correct way to play nice with mongodb in nodejs** when a single launch callback isn't enough?

I imagine a module that you pass queries in callback-form, which passes the callbacks around for you, either (1) to where it waits for the connection-callback, (2) directly to the collection, or (3) waiting for the connection, but too late for the connection-callback. But like I said, this is pure syntactic saccharin.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Deferred object for your database connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand something. First you create the connection to DB:

```
var mDb = new Db('SomeDatabase', mServer);
```

and you hold the reference to this connection. Whenever you want to load/save something from/to DB, you use **the same** variable. You don't recreate it on every request. Initialization should be done even before creating the web server itself ( create the server on `open` callback ). Here's a pseudo code:

```
var webserver = INITIALIZE_NEW_SERVER( );
var mDB = new Db('SomeDatabase', mServer);

// set request handler
WHEN_REQUEST ---> {
    mDB.createCollection( ... );
    // whatever
}

mDb.open(function(error, newDb) {
    // handle errors
    webserver.listen( );
});
```

Comment: But if database i/o is only going to happen at a certain hour, people generally use `mDB.close()` and you can't have it influence whether or not your server is running.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the difference between the original `mDb` and the callback `newDb`? As in: Why are they consistently named `client` and `pClient` in articles?

Comment: @Redsandro `mDb` and `newDb` both refer to the same object.

Comment: @Redsandro I don't know what articles you are talking about. Also I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to prevent your server from connecting with DB except for the particular hour? Then just look at current time on request and keep the connection open all the time. It is easier to handle and keeping connection open with DB all the time has almost none overhead. And ( as you noticed ) it has one big advantage: it scales well, while creating connections all the time does not.

Comment: @freakish You can google `mongodb "pClient"` and see that `pClient` is widely used in the callback, while `client` is used for the actual commands. According to JohnnyHK, they refer to the same object. But I've never seen the `pClient` one used. What's it for then?  
As for the database, it just feels wrong to have the database invoke the entire server in stead of the other way around. If node restarts, and the db is temporarily unavailable, I want the server to start and skip the db stuff until it becomes available.

Comment: @Redsandro It's not wrong. It is a common practice to open database connection *before* starting the server. The only reason to do what you are trying to do is when you do not have control over the database, i.e. you are trying to connect to an external database. But that's really inefficient anyway, so you should use ( for example ) a cron job to pull the data from the external database to your own. In order to avoid such situations.